In a Hilbert space, the interior of an angle contains an infinite number of points.

Prove that in Hilbert space (satisfying axioms of incidence and axioms of betweeness), the interior of an angle contains
infinite points.

PS: The inside (or interior) of an angle $\widehat{BAC}$ consists of all points $D$ such that $D$ and $C$ are on the same side of the line $AB$, and $D$ and $B$ are on the same side of the line $AC$.
I have proven the following results:

For every pair of $A,B$ distinct, there exists $C$ such that $C$ lies between $A$ and $B$.
The interior of an angle is nonempty (which is easily proven by using 1.)
Consider the angle $\widehat{xAy}$. Take $B\in\vec{Ax}, C\in\vec{Ay}$. By 1), there exists $D$ s.t $D$ lies between $B,C$
Since $B,D$ lie on the same side of the line $Ay$, $C,D$ lie on the same side of the line $Ax$, $D\in$ the interior of $\widehat{xAy}$.
So, the interior of $\widehat{xAy}$ is nonempty.
Every line contains infinite points

I don't know how to show that the interior of an angle contains infinite points. I would be very much grateful if someone can help me. Thanks in advance!
For more information of mathematical definitions, please consider page 66 (axioms of incidence) and page 73 (axioms of betweeness)
https://david92jackson.neocities.org/images/Euclid_and_Beyond-Hartshorne.pdf

It sounds like you've copied a problem from an unnamed source.  Knowing the source of a problem often let's Readers respond in a way that matches the intent of the author of the problem to reinforce earlier lessons.  You say (2) is "easily proven" by using (1) but this is not clear to me.  $AB$ would appear to be one side (ray) of the angle $\widehat{BAC}$, so not actually in the "interior" of the angle as normally meant.

@hardmath i edited

All interior points of segment $BC$ are also interior points of angle $BAC$.

@Intelligentipauca How to prove segment $BC$ contains infinite interior points?

There is a point $C$ between $A$ and $B$; there is a point $D$ between $A$ and $C$; there is a point $E$ between $A$ and $D$; there is ...

"infinite points" $\to$ "infinite number of points"
